# Using Python's xlsxwriter to drop a tabulated html file into worksheet - is this possible?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I just wanted to know if it is possible to insert the contents of a local tabulated html file into an Excel worksheet using xlsxwriter?  Manually it works fine by just dragging and dropping the file into Excel and the formatting is clear, but I can't find any information on inserting file contents into Excel using xlsxwriter.  I can only find information related to inserting an image into Excel.

Many thanks for reading this,
MikG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such functionality is not what xlsxwriter offers.

This package is able to write Excel files, but as importing HTML you describe is using MS Excell GUI functionality and as MS Excel is not an requirement of `xlsxwriter`, do not expect it to be present.

On the other hand, you could play with Python to do the conversion of HTML to spreadsheet data yourself, it is definitely not drag and drop solution, but for repetitive tasks this can be much more productive at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the update, at least i know not to keep researching this.